# Python's IDLE for Java

Tags: java, python, ide, debugging

Question: IS there and IDE like python's [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) for other languages? specifically I'd like one for java, but any programing just feels so much nicer with a debug system like IDLE's.

---

Info:

The main feature I'm getting at is the ability to test programs. In IDLE I can have the editor for my class in one window, i save and run it then IDLE pops up. it there was anything to run, such happens. but If I'm making just the classes and not the full program it just sits there with a dumb look on it's face. I type in for example:

```
a = foo(%constructor params%)
```

and now a is an instantiation of foo and i can test any of the functions i want at will:

```
a.bar("function call params!")
```

and then foo.bar runs. it is incredibly useful for debugging. But I've only ever seen it in python. But would really like it in java, where I have to write a whole separate class in order to do anything. which is incredibly annoying.

---

Conclusion:

Thank you those who answered. recursive, TwentyMiles, recursive, Justin Ethier, and especially recursive... recursive... The wikipedia page is wonderful. a REPL was what I was looking for.

P.S. sorry for the lack of info, I was in a hurry and forgot. one of those moments your you have it in your head that you know what you mean, surely everyone else does...

Comment: There are IDEs for just about any language you can think of.

If you're asking for an IDE that resembles IDLE in some way, what is it specifically about IDLE that you like?

Comment: "Like IDLE" is not a very good description. Could you tell us which features *specifically* you'd like to see in the IDE?

Comment: These interfaces are known as REPLs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop

Comment: Other languages?  In general?  How would that work for a language that's compiled to native binaries like C?

Comment: For C, there's actually c-repl: http://neugierig.org/software/c-repl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about a REPL (Read Eval Print Loop), or some sort of console where you can test out code without having to compile the whole project/file, [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) is the best I've found for Java. It isn't tightly integrated with an IDE, like IDLE, but with a language like Java it's about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

[BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/index.html) is probably the closest thing available in the Java community.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) has an interactive shell when at break points as well, it is a little calculator icon in the debug panel when at a break point. Also since [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) is a **superset** of Java, you can write straight up Java in its interactive shell as well.

Comment: where did you get Eclipse? and while yes, the function I'm talking about is basically like breaks points. IDLE's ability to just take commands as i give them is incredibly valuable and so much more powerful than break points

Comment: GroovyShell is probably the best thing you will find to interactively execute Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Jshell is integrated into the JDK download, and works like IDLE.

Just type `jshell` in Command Prompt.